# Acrobat Form: How to Create a button to unlock or make readable form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat, locked

I am working on an Acrobat Form, and would like the user (who is using reader) to be able to send/submit a locked PDF for record keeping, without all of the form buttons (submit, clear), and then be able to return to editing the form and have the form buttons reapear.

I have easily found how to lock and submit the form, using this code within a button.

for

```
 (var i=0; i<this.numFields; i++) 

 {var fname = this.getNthFieldName(i);

 var f = this.getField(fname);

 if (f.type!="button") f.readonly = true;}
 this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:name@email.com"});
```

But I can't seem to find the code on how to unlock fields anywhere.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I have found a partial solution, even if it's not the most elegant, or efficient. 

On the Mouse Up Action, I run a Script that Locks all fields, and hides the three form buttons. I also set the submit form action. This successfully sends a copy of the document removing remnants of the form to the end user. 

This works for everything except the actual submit button itself. After it's been hidden, the mouse exit no longer works. 

I then set a script on mouse exit that makes the fields unlocked (readonly=false) and set the hidden attribute to false as well.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "record keeping", you could just set the buttons to be visible on screen but not print.